Connect to Google Photos API from Google Colab
I made a Google Cloud Project and Enabled Google Photos API and OAuth 2.0.
In Google Colab, the authenticate() brings up a popup asking for permissions of Google Drive. If I provide client_secret.json instead I get other kind of errors including inability to start a server, scopes and other permission issues.
I will be using this to download large videos from Google Photos to Colab environment, compress them using ffmpeg and upload them back.
So far I am failing at the initial steps of connecting to Photos API.
What is the correct way to connect to Photos via API using Google colab?

In Colab, you need to provide a secret.
Look into that by going here:
https://medium.com/@parthdasawant/how-to-use-secrets-in-google-colab-450c38e3ec75
or here:
https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs?hl=fr
Enjoy

This is what worked at the end. Please note the in google cloud console, when you create OAuth credential, its type should be Desktop App, NOT Web.
import os

import typing
import requests
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build, Resource
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload, MediaFileUpload
from google.colab import files


def create_credentials(secrets_path: str, scopes: typing.List[str]) -> Credentials:
    path = os.path.splitext(secrets_path)[0]
    tokens_path = f'{path}-cached-token.json'

    if os.path.exists(tokens_path):
        credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(tokens_path, scopes)
    else:
        credentials = None

    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(secrets_path, scopes, redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
            auth_url, _ = flow.authorization_url(prompt='consent')
            print("Please visit this URL to authorize the application: " + auth_url)
            # Wait for the user to paste the authorization code
            auth_code = input("Enter the authorization code: ")
            flow.fetch_token(code=auth_code)
            credentials = flow.credentials
            #clear_output()

        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open(tokens_path, 'w') as token:
            token.write(credentials.to_json())

    return credentials


def create_photos_service(secrets_path: str) -> Resource:
    credentials = create_credentials(
        secrets_path,
        [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary'
        ]
    )

    return build('photoslibrary', 'v1', credentials=credentials, static_discovery=False)

